# How do I convert a list of tuples and number to a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi Stackoverflow geeks,

I have this list:

```
[(('Male', 'White'), 6488)]
```

& I want to convert it to a tuple like this:

```
('Male', 'White', 6488)
```

I appreciate if you help me with the code.

Comment: How is this linked to pandas?

Comment: Assuming `l` the list: `l[0][0] + (l[0][1],)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalised solution to flatten lists that contain a possible combination of iterables and non-iterables of various types:

```
import functools
from typing import Any, Iterable, List


def ext(x: List, y: Any) -> List:
    """
    Returns x, extended or appended to include the individual constituents of y.
    x is always a list. y may or may not be. 
    """

    # Because strings are iterable, we don't want them to be broken down
    # into individual characters - so we check that y is iterable but not a 
    # string.

    if isinstance(y, Iterable) and not isinstance(y, str):
        x.extend(y)
    else:
        x.append(y)

    return x
```

Use the above function with `functools.reduce` to work your way through the original iterable, accumulating its contents into a single list.
You provide `[]` as an initial value for `x` passed into `ext`, to guarantee that it is always a `list` for the purposes of `ext`. Once you have that `list`, convert it into a `tuple` to give you your desired result.

Trying this on your original problem - `arr1` below, you need to run this approach twice, because your original iterable only contains one iterable of its own:

```
arr1 = [('Male', 'White'), 6488]
result1 = tuple(functools.reduce(ext, arr1, []))
print (result1)

# Result -> (('Male', 'White'), 6488)

result1 = tuple(functools.reduce(ext, result1, []))
print(result1)

# Result -> ('Male', 'White', 6488)
```

Trying it on a more complex object:

```
arr2 = [('foo'), 'bar', ['bleep', 'bloop'], {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
result2 = tuple(functools.reduce(ext, arr2, []))
print(result2)

# Result -> ('foo', 'bar', 'bleep', 'bloop', 'a', 'b')
```

Note that with dictionaries, you only get the `keys` back. If you want key/value pairs, you'll need to add a specific guard for this, like so:

```
def ext2(x: List, y: Any) -> List:
    """
    Reworking ext to deal differently with dictionaries in the original iterable.
    """
    if isinstance(y, Iterable) and not isinstance(y, str):
        if isinstance(y, dict):
            x.extend(y.items())
        else:
            x.extend(y)
    else:
        x.append(y)

    return x
```

Trying it again on the last example::

```
arr2 = [('foo'), 'bar', ['bleep', 'bloop'], {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
result3 = tuple(functools.reduce(ext2, arr2, []))
print(result3)

# Result -> ('foo', 'bar', 'bleep', 'bloop', ('a', 1), ('b', 2))
```